# Self referencing loop causing stack overflow with map

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, automapper-6

According to the documentation PreserveReferences should be set automatically whenever possible for AutoMapper.

> Starting from 6.1.0 PreserveReferences is set automatically at config
>   time whenever possible.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide

I have also tried setting MaxDepth to 1 but I still get a stack overflow exception with the following mapping. Can I get around this somehow or do I need to modify the view models?

```
cfg.CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>(MemberList.Source)
    .MaxDepth(1)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);
```

Code that causes the stack overflow exception:

```
var article = await iArticleRepository.GetAsync(id);
//The mapping below causes the exception
var mappedArticle = Mapper.Map<ArticleViewModel>(article);
```

Entities:

```
public class Article: IEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public int SupplierId { get; set; }

    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier: IEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact: IEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

View models:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
    public SupplierViewModel Supplier { get; set; }

}

public class SupplierViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
    public List<ContactViewModel> Contacts { get; set; }

}

public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... 
    public List<SupplierViewModel> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your Contact entity has a collection of other Contacts while your ContactViewModel has a collection of SuplierViewModels. Is that correct?

Comment: @Fabiano Thanks for noticing and no it should of course be Suppliers. Updated now.

Comment: Hopefully for people who have hundreds of CreateMap (like us) it is possible to add PreserveReferences for all maps with one single line of code : cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) => mappingExpression.PreserveReferences()); Unfortunately doing so we won't benefits of performance improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's unclear what does *whenever possible* mean. Since the documentation before that states

> It turns out this tracking is very expensive, and you need to opt-in using PreserveReferences for circular maps to work

looks like your scenario fails into *not possible* category :)

Let not rely on that and use the explicit opt-in. The circular reference in this sample model is between `Supplier` and `Contact`, so you have to specify in one of the involved class mappings, for instance:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>(MemberList.Source)
    .MaxDepth(1)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);

cfg.CreateMap<SupplierViewModel, Supplier>(MemberList.Source)
    .PreserveReferences()
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with this before but without MaxDepth. When using both however it worked! Will update your answer and mark as accepted.